# creating an 'ever event' variable from an 'incident event' variable

Tags: r

In R, in a repeated measures dataset, how can I create a variable that is the same for each measurement on an individual based upon an incident variable? For instance if I have:

```
id incident_MI
1 0
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 0
2 0
3 0
3 0
3 0
3 1
```

And I want to use the `incident_MI` to create an `ever_MI` variable like this:

```
id incident_MI Ever_MI
1 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
2 0 0
2 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 1
3 0 1
3 0 1
3 1 1
```

Any ideas on how I might code that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check for `any` 1's in the 'incident_MI' after grouping by 'id' and convert it to 'numeric' with `as.integer` to create the 'Ever_MI'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(Ever_MI = as.integer(any(incident_MI==1)))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups: id [3]
#      id incident_MI Ever_MI
#   <int>       <int>   <int>
# 1     1           0       1
# 2     1           0       1
# 3     1           1       1
# 4     2           0       0
# 5     2           0       0
# 6     2           0       0
# 7     3           0       1
# 8     3           0       1
# 9     3           0       1
#10     3           1       1
```

---

Or as @lmo commented, the `data.table` option would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Ever_MI := any(incident_MI), by=.(id)][]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$Ever_MI <- with(df1, ave(incident_MI, id, FUN = any))
```

Comment: thank you! df1$Ever_MI <- with(df1, ave(incident_MI, id, FUN = any)) worked perfectly!

Comment: and to complete the unholy trinity, its `df1[, Ever_MI := any(incident_MI), by="id"]` in `data.table`.